# Checkbox path aliasing

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have created a checkbox in WPF it works but looks really ugly the tick in the box is very jagged. I have tried to set the RenderOptions.EdgeMode to aliased but that hasn't fixed it, am I missing something?

the code is as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxFocusVisual}" />        
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FGBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderOptions.EdgeMode" Value="Aliased"/>        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Grid Width="12" Height="12" MinHeight="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MinimumIteractSizeDips}"
                                        MinWidth="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MinimumIteractSizeDips}" 
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">

                                <Border x:Name="Border" 
                                        BitmapEffect="{StaticResource DropShadow}"
                                        MinHeight="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MinimumIteractSizeDips}"
                                        MinWidth="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MinimumIteractSizeDips}"
                                        CornerRadius="0" 
                                        Background="{StaticResource GreyGradientBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">

                                    <!--<Path Stretch="Fill"
                                              Margin="3"
                                                x:Name="CheckMark"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
                                    Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                                    StrokeThickness="3"
                                    Fill="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}"
                                          RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                    Data="M103.78572,598.96112 L105.09846,597.5661 L107.00806,600.16229 C107.00806,600.16229 109.91004,592.74463 109.91004,592.74463 C109.91004,592.74463 111.74678,593.79761 111.74678,593.79761 C111.74678,593.79761 107.88566,602.75848 107.88566,602.75848 L106.60118,602.75848 z" />-->


                                    <Path Stretch="Fill"
                                              Margin="3"
                                                x:Name="CheckMark"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
                                    Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                                    StrokeThickness="3"
                                    Fill="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}"
                                          RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                    Data="M103.78572,598.96112 L105.09846,597.5661 L107.00806,600.16229 C107.00806,600.16229 109.91004,592.74463 109.91004,592.74463 C109.91004,592.74463 111.74678,593.79761 111.74678,593.79761 C111.74678,593.79761 107.88566,602.75848 107.88566,602.75848 L106.60118,602.75848 z" />

                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Data" Value="M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                        </Trigger>-->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="HighlightAnim">
                                    <Storyboard TargetName="Border" TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="00:00:00.1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="HighlightAnim"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess I would say it has something to do with all the decimals in your `Path` object, or perhaps the fact it's  `Stretch=Fill`

This is the default CheckBox `Path`

```
<Path Visibility="Collapsed"
      Width="7"
      Height="7"
      x:Name="CheckMark"
      SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
      StrokeThickness="2"
      Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0">
      <Path.Stroke>
           <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
      </Path.Stroke>
 </Path>
```

And this is your `Path`

```
<Path Stretch="Fill"
      Margin="3"
      x:Name="CheckMark"
      SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
      Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
      StrokeThickness="3"
      Fill="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}"
      RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
      Data="M103.78572,598.96112 L105.09846,597.5661 L107.00806,600.16229 C107.00806,600.16229 109.91004,592.74463 109.91004,592.74463 C109.91004,592.74463 111.74678,593.79761 111.74678,593.79761 C111.74678,593.79761 107.88566,602.75848 107.88566,602.75848 L106.60118,602.75848 z" />
```

I would suggest altering properties one at a time to change your version to the MSDN version, and see which one fixes the issue. I am guessing it's `Path.Data`, but it could be one of the other properties as well.

Comment: Stretch="Fill" was set as I need to be able to re-size the controls. There must be a way to be able to get the image to resize smoothly.

Comment: @user1145533 Did you try putting it in a `ViewBox`?

Comment: Just gave that a go and the tick now looks much better although for some reason it is now much bigger then the box. Any idea why the ViewBox is so big? Also how did you get the default values for the checkbox?

Comment: @user1145533 The default control templates for all WPF controls can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx). As to the ViewBox, I'm not sure without testing the code myself. Try resizing it to fit your content area.